# Error 'unexpected end of file /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh' by vagrant up command

Tags: vagrant, debian, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I tried to do `vagrant up`.
My environment on Host machine

- Microsoft Windows 10
- Virtual Box 5.1.10
- Vagrant 1.8.6

Vagrant got box `bento/debian-8.6`, setuped ports, mounted shared folders and after that returned error

```
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 10: $'\r': command not found
==> myvag: Updating Aptitude
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 14: $'\r': command not found
==> myvag: Removing exim4
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 20: $'\r': command not found
==> myvag: Performing an safe-upgrade
==> myvag: Reading changelogs...
==> myvag: Done with safe-upgrade
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 25: $'\r': command not found
==> myvag: Adding dotdeb dependencies to apt sources if not there.
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 27: $'\r': command not found
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 30: $'\r': command not found
==> myvag: Adding dotdeb GPG Key
==> myvag: /vagrant/provision/prep_server.sh: line 42: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Content from this file is below

```
#!/bin/bash

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

############ Ultimately, this is a HACK: ###############
## Because of libssl and heartbleed, there are some
## debian propts that come up and destroy screw up
## Our provisioning scripts in salt and make the output
## really funny.

# Update our packages data
echo "Updating Aptitude"
sudo aptitude update > /dev/null

# exim4 is the stupid package causing the prompt to occur.
# It was just easier to remove it than automate the lib's
# Upgrade screen.
echo "Removing exim4"
sudo aptitude purge -y -q -f exim4 > /dev/null

echo "Performing an safe-upgrade"
# Do an upgrade of the existing stuff
sudo -E bash -c 'aptitude safe-upgrade -y -f > /dev/null'
echo "Done with safe-upgrade"

echo "Adding dotdeb dependencies to apt sources if not there."
grep -q -F 'packages.dotdeb.org' /etc/apt/sources.list ||
echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

echo "Adding dotdeb GPG Key"
if ! apt-key list | grep -q -F  'dotdeb'; then
    wget https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
    apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
    rm dotdeb.gpg
else
    echo "Dotdeb GPG Key present"
fi

echo "Updating apt-get"
apt-get update
```

As I understand it can be related with endings \r\n, but how can I fix that.

In the same time my colleague don't have troubles with `vagrant up`, but he uses Ubuntu on host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has carriage return encoded by windows which is different in linux world.

Your solutions:

1. run your file through dos2unix script (http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net)
2. most advanced editors on windows (UltraEdit, Notepad++) allows you to save the format of the file specifically for linux (for example UltraEdit has File/convert with option to convert for linux)

Comment: What do you mean "rub file"., I run command vagrant up and this file are created automatically

Comment: The file is not created by vagrant this is your own provision script you need to make sure it is not encoded with Windows specific carriage return